# How to use COUNT in this SQL Query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, records

My question is really simple, I need to count how many results this query has because there're too many records in this ugly database and the PHP code is using too much memory to pull all the records. I'm gonna count how many records this query generates and with PHP i'm gonna use a loop to pull 10k records at a time.

This is the query:

```
SELECT p.Email,
            c.ID_Cliente,
            c.DataHoraUltimaAtualizacaoILR,
            p.Nome, 
            upper(substring(p.Nome, 1, charindex(' ', p.Nome + ' '))) as 'PrimeiroNome',
            p.DataHoraCadastro, 
            p.Sexo, 
            p.EstadoCivil, 
            p.DataNascimento, 
            getdate() as [today],
            datediff (yy,p.DataNascimento,getdate()) as 'Idade',
            datepart(month,p.DataNascimento) as 'MesAniversario',
            e.Bairro,
            e.Cidade, 
            e.UF, 
            c.CodLoja as codloja_cadastro,
            t.DDD,
            t.Numero
from PessoaFisica p
left join Cliente c on (c.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
left join Loja l on (cast(l.CodLoja as integer) = cast(c.CodLoja as integer))
left join PessoaEndereco pe on (pe.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
left join Endereco e on (e.ID_Endereco = pe.ID_Endereco)
left join PessoaTelefone pt on (pt.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
left join Telefone t on (t.ID_Telefone = pt.ID_Telefone)
where p.Email is not NULL and p.Email <> ''
group by p.Email, c.ID_Cliente, p.Nome, p.EstadoCivil, p.DataHoraCadastro, c.CodLoja, p.Sexo, e.Bairro, p.DataNascimento, e.Cidade, e.UF, c.DataHoraUltimaAtualizacaoILR, t.DDD, t.Numero
```

I already tried this (bellow) but the count is different from the total of results of this query, it has to match:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.Email)
FROM PessoaFisica p
left join Cliente c on (c.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
left join Loja l on (cast(l.CodLoja as integer) = cast(c.CodLoja as integer))
left join PessoaEndereco pe on (pe.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
left join Endereco e on (e.ID_Endereco = pe.ID_Endereco)
left join PessoaTelefone pt on (pt.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
left join Telefone t on (t.ID_Telefone = pt.ID_Telefone)
where p.Email is not NULL and p.Email <> ''
```

**I'm using MS SQL Server**

Comment: select count(*) from ( ...put your first query here... );

Comment: @Multisync Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: if you want result of above query as well as count then put `select @@rowcount` after your query. otherwise answer suggested by @multisync will do your work. Also, no need to specify the aliases as 'PrimeiroNome', just use PrimeiroNome or [PrimeiroNome]

Comment: @user2315555 the query is causing me an error, I'm using MSSQL, maybe it's different?

Comment: where did you put @@rowcount?  @@rowcount works in mssql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your query inside `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) AS tbl` as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT 
        p.Email,
        c.ID_Cliente,
        c.DataHoraUltimaAtualizacaoILR,
        p.Nome, 
        upper(substring(p.Nome, 1, charindex(' ', p.Nome + ' '))) as 'PrimeiroNome',
        p.DataHoraCadastro, 
        p.Sexo, 
        p.EstadoCivil, 
        p.DataNascimento, 
        getdate() as [today],
        datediff (yy,p.DataNascimento,getdate()) as 'Idade',
        datepart(month,p.DataNascimento) as 'MesAniversario',
        e.Bairro,
        e.Cidade, 
        e.UF, 
        c.CodLoja as codloja_cadastro,
        t.DDD,
        t.Numero
    from PessoaFisica p
    left join Cliente c on (c.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
    left join Loja l on (cast(l.CodLoja as integer) = cast(c.CodLoja as integer))
    left join PessoaEndereco pe on (pe.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
    left join Endereco e on (e.ID_Endereco = pe.ID_Endereco)
    left join PessoaTelefone pt on (pt.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
    left join Telefone t on (t.ID_Telefone = pt.ID_Telefone)
    where p.Email is not NULL and p.Email <> ''
    group by p.Email, c.ID_Cliente, p.Nome, p.EstadoCivil, p.DataHoraCadastro, 
    c.CodLoja, p.Sexo, e.Bairro, p.DataNascimento, e.Cidade, e.UF, 
    c.DataHoraUltimaAtualizacaoILR, t.DDD, t.Numero
) AS tbl
```

Comment: It didn't worked (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'. )

Comment: Are you sure the inner select works? If so, the above query should also work.

Answer (score 0):

After @ekad's answer:

You should not select all the fields and do all the calculations to count the results, you can use only one column or a scalar value too:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT 
        1
    from PessoaFisica p
    left join Cliente c on (c.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
    left join Loja l on (cast(l.CodLoja as integer) = cast(c.CodLoja as integer))
    left join PessoaEndereco pe on (pe.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
    left join Endereco e on (e.ID_Endereco = pe.ID_Endereco)
    left join PessoaTelefone pt on (pt.ID_Pessoa = p.ID_PessoaFisica)
    left join Telefone t on (t.ID_Telefone = pt.ID_Telefone)
    where p.Email is not NULL and p.Email <> ''
    group by p.Email, c.ID_Cliente, p.Nome, p.EstadoCivil, p.DataHoraCadastro, 
    c.CodLoja, p.Sexo, e.Bairro, p.DataNascimento, e.Cidade, e.UF, 
    c.DataHoraUltimaAtualizacaoILR, t.DDD, t.Numero
) AS tbl
```

Comment: SQL Server's optimiser is smart enough to know that those fields are not needed and the query you have posted and the query posted by @ekad will yield the same execution plan. The only benefit of this is that it is more legible, and the intent is clearer (Although you will need to alias the column rather than just `SELECT 1`)

Answer (score 0):

this may also work :

```
;with cte (Email,ID_Cliente,DataHoraUltimaAtualizacaoILR,Nome, PrimeiroNome,DataHoraCadastro, 
Sexo, EstadoCivil, DataNascimento, today,Idade,MesAniversario,Bairro,Cidade, 
UF, codloja_cadastro,DDD,numero) as 
(
...... your query.....
)
select count(*) from cte
```